# nodejs push in array with different syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if what is possible in javascript with cookies is doable somehow in node.js for example

```
document.cookie="sss=fff;";
```

i want to define a method in the an object that behaves like this, and instead of making the variable equal to the string it pushes it in an array.

```
function o(){
this.add=[]
}
var o1= new o();
o.add="sss=fff;";
```

Comment: Arrays support push(). Unless I misunderstand, o.add.push("sss=fff;") will do what you want.
EDIT: Oh I see, you want the assignment to _behave_ like a push.

Comment: I know, but i am talking about the syntax.

Comment: This is a really neat question. It looks like Object.watch or Object.observe will allow you to listen to variable changes. I suppose you could make a callback that pushes onto the array when you try to modify it. This might be of use: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Operator Overriding vs. Getter and Setter

There is no way to override operators in JavaScript. `=` is always and only used for assignment. You can on the other hand use getter and setter definitions on an object to perform special operations on values before they are set or retrieved.

Reference: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

**Example:**

```
function o(){
    values = [];
    this.__defineSetter__("add", function(v){
        values.push(v);
    });
    this.__defineGetter__("add", function(){
        return values.join("");
    });

}
```